# Spring Bean update and model update (Spring/Hibernate/Roo/MySQL)

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, roo

I have to add some functionalities to a Spring Web App (not written by me), to do so I would like to modify beans/alter table models, but I don't know where to start, maybe this is not the right way to proceed on a spring-hibernate project.

What is the best practice?

Checking pom.xml previous developer used:

```
roo 1.2.3
mysql 5.1.18
hibernate 4.18
spring 3.2.0
```

This is my first time using hibernate/spring/roo and I'm really struggling, any help would be very appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What did you try? This question is not specific enough to answer.

Comment: In a nutshell, I have to add and bu able to use a new attribute of an object.
I added the new attribute, the getter, the setter in the entity and added a column in the table but I can't build.

Comment: I forgot this question... so i solved this: I brutally altered tables, modified beans and updated methods, worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

I forgot this question... so i solved this: I brutally altered tables, modified beans and updated methods, worked like a charm :)